# how can i add new college when search results empty on facebook graph api

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api, search

```
    require_once( $C->INCPATH.'classes/class_facebook.php');

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $C->FACEBOOK_API_ID,
        'secret' => $C->FACEBOOK_API_SECRET,
    ));


    $mySrch = $facebook->api('/search?q=ghjghjghjghjhg&type=adeducationschool');
```

Forexample; I am searching "ghjghjghjghjhg" named universty via graph api so api returns empty response. How can i add "ghjghjghjghjhg" named universty on facebook platform for to show this universty on new search result via graph api.